# SQL Server trigger : when a new row is inserted if column A is blank or null SET value to X

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to create a SQL Server trigger so that when a new row is inserted in `CONTACT`, if column `Contact_Type` is blank `''` or `NULL`, it should be set to `PCON`.

The trigger I have created doesn't work. I have not created any triggers before so I am well out of my depth, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I assume I am messing something up in my where clause in regards to the inserted table?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EJ_ConTACT_TYPE_DefaultValue_INS] 
ON [dbo].[CONTACT] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        
    DECLARE @defaultvalue varchar(6) = 'PCON'

    UPDATE [dbo].[CONTACT]
    SET Contact_Type = @defaultvalue
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE [dbo].[CONTACT].[Contact_Type] = i.Contact_Type
      AND (i.[Contact_Type] = '' OR i.[Contact_Type] = NULL)
END
GO
```

Comment: Why not set a `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` on your column, and ensure it is ommited from the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Also, what does "doesn' work" mean? What isn't working about it?

Comment: Should your `= NULL` be `is NULL` ?   Make sure the update query does what you need when run directly.

Comment: Adding to @Grax32 's comment never use `= NULL` since that predicate will yield `UNKNOWN`, which is neither true nor false. Use `IS NULL` to check for `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, like I mention in the comments, I would simply create a default constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Contact ADD CONSTRAINT df_Contact_ContactType DEFAULT 'PCON' FOR Contact_Type;
```

Then you simply omit the column in your `INSERT` and the column will have the value. For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Contact (Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES('abc',1,'20200916');
```

This will cause the column `Contact_Type` to have the value `'PCON'`.

As for why your trigger isn't working, one problem is because of your `WHERE`. `[dbo].[CONTACT].[ConTACT_TYPE] = i.ConTACT_TYPE` will **never** be true is the column `ConTACT_TYPE` (does your column really have that odd casing in it's name..?) if it's value is `NULL`; `NULL` is equal to nothing including `NULL` itself. This also applies to your clause `OR [ConTACT_TYPE] = NULL`. Finally, I doubt that that value is unique, so it'll update rows it shouldn't.

If you "must" do this in a `TRIGGER` (I suggest you don't), use the Primary Key for the `JOIN`. Also, don't use 3+ part naming for columns: [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/). This results in the below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EJ_Contact_Type_DefaultValue] ON [dbo].[contact]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        
        --DECLARE @defaultvalue varchar(6) = 'PCON'

        UPDATE C
        SET Contact_type = 'PCON'
        FROM dbo.Contact C
             JOIN inserted i ON C.ID = i.ID
        WHERE i.Contact_type = ''
           OR i.Contact_type IS NULL;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you Larnu

Users create this record using a form in an application. If they were to select another option say 'PCLI' would that override the default constraint or would the row still show 'PCON'? 

If you think that is odd casing you should see some of the other tables! I have just inherited this database a few weeks back and if the column ConTACT_TYPE is blank or NULL it stops another feature in the application from working as it requires a value in this field.

Thanks for the tip on IS NULL rather than = NULL and I will look into 3+ part naming.

Comment: *"If they were to select another option say 'PCLI' would that override the default constraint"* A `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` is only used if a column is omitted from an `INSERT`.

Comment: So if the INSERT is adding the value ' ' rather than NULL the DEFAULT CONSTRAINT would not apply then?

Comment: Correct, @JRDavis91 . Again, from both my comments and the answer above... *"Then you simply omit the column in your INSERT and the column will have the value. For example: ..."* I even demonstrate this, so I am not sure what you are not understanding here.

Comment: Sorry @Larnu new to SQL so very limited knowledge. 
I have tried your amended Trigger but that did not change the value that was inserted into the table.

I am going to test adding a default constraint, but the value doesn't appear to ever be NULL I have done a DISTINCT Select on that field and no NULL's appeared. I was putting NULL there to cover it, the value always appears to be a blank field ' '  and the value can be something other than PCON such as PCLI or FEXEC.
I think I may be way out of my depth, and I am 100% not explaining myself correctly. Sorry

Comment: *"I have tried your amended Trigger but that did not change the value that was inserted into the table."* then there is something you aren't telling us here, @JRDavis91 , or you *aren't* inserting `NULL` or `''`. Time for you to take the time to supply an [mre].

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://imgur.com/a/Ualqp8x The first image shows a section of the CONTACT table with the blank value in ConTACT_TYPE
The second image is showing the DISTINCT values for ConTACT_TYPE.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EJ_ConTACT_TYPE_DefaultValue_INS] 
   ON  [dbo].[CONTACT] 
   AFTER INSERT
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
    UPDATE C
        SET ConTACT_TYPE = 'PCON'
        FROM dbo.Contact C
             JOIN inserted i ON C.NAME_DIWOR = i.NAME_DIWOR
        WHERE i.ConTACT_TYPE = ''
           OR i.ConTACT_TYPE IS NULL;

END
GO
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that jumble doesn't mean anything, @JRDavis91 .

Comment: As you can see from this [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e32be78d27bcb4ea22e97085778e830) though, the above *does* work, meaning, like I said, something else is wrong that you aren't telling us.

Comment: Yeah tried adding the code with ``` but didnt work for comments... https://imgur.com/a/Ualqp8x should have another screenshot attached

Comment: Like I said before, @JRDavis91, provide an [mre]... Images of code, and data, are *not* helpful.

Comment: Sorry @larnu I'm new to this :(. So where you use ID would that be my NAME_DIWOR? That is what is used to link across the tables, but there are no PK or FK on the table!

Comment: thanks for the Fiddle link that helped so much! I tried just using the INSERT INTO on the table and guess what! The trigger worked!!! There must be something going on with this Application which is stopping the Trigger from starting when it inserts the row! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: changed the  " AFTER INSERT " to " AFTER INSERT, UPDATE " and its working when creating a contact via the application.... So when its entering a row its treating it like an update, i guess the application is inserting a row which would be blank with PCON in the ConTACT_TYPE field then that is being overwritten by an update somewhere which is writing over the PCON!